# list of ms word 2007 application-/object-specific runtime errors

Tags: vba, ms-word, word-2007

is there any list or online resource available that translates application and/or object specific error codes from ms word 2007 into meaningful information? something similar to  [this compilation for ms access](http://www.fmsinc.com/microsoftaccess/errors/errornumber_description.html) would be great.

specifically i'm searching for an explanation of error 5496 when saving the document.

thx in advance